# Reading doc files from SharePoint returns null

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, csom

My scenario: i am trying to read doc file from SharePoint 2019 server.My application is running on a separate  IIS server. For docx file my code works well(not shown here)  but not for doc.

> Error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

```
                       Application application = new Application();

                        Document document = application.Documents.Open(resultRow["Path"].ToString());

                        Filebody = document.Words.ToString();
```

Comment: above error is coming on which line ? line document.Words.ToString() ?

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia Yes that line. I check the value of document using a breakpoint it is null